# Image editing library for Windows 8

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Do we have any image editing library that can work on windows 8 platform? I tried using Aforge.net but VS2012 gave error that it is not compatible with Metro UI apps while importing the library

Comment: What functionality are you looking for? The WriteableBitmapEX library offers some basic functionality similar to GDI+. Check it at http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: You will have to design a compatible library if your trying to write a Windows Store Application.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Does WriteableBitmapEx also allow to draw text on the image? I have quickly looked at the project on CodePlex and have not seen a DrawText-function (for curiosity only, I know that the OP has not asked for this).

Comment: WinRT XAML Toolkit has a new component now that has a partial implementation of WriteableBitmap.Render() which you can use to render text to images.

Comment: @HCL, currently you get all basic functionality regarding image manipulation in WriteableBitmapEX. However, Text manipulation is still difficult - unless you're using ink to write text. What I mean over here is - text 'typed' can't be stored as part of image.

Comment: I am trying to make an app for windows 8 where a person can make his own effect. Basically giving access to all the basic function like shading and blending so that the user can create his own effect by just sequencing them and storing the sequence and share with others.

Comment: @Filip Skakun: Great! Does the composition engine (including text rendering) also work on ARM-based Win-RT?

Comment: Yes, it uses SharpDX which works fine on ARM. It is still a bit limited though - I haven't actually added options to render Image controls, it does not handle Opacity, Visibility, Clip or RenderTransforms etc. but it might get there with time and you can help make it get there too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you can use SharpDx ; A well build C# lib that support plenty of editing functionality, Or you can use Aviary sdk for image editing. SharpDx is free and you need to spend some $ for Aviary sdk.

Comment: Thats somthing what what i am looking for..... BUT its based on DirectX, dnt have much knowledge on it. :(

Comment: That is correct, it is based on DirectX, But the C# implementation samples are available in the site, form those you can build your app. Also the forum is also very active yo will get instant response about your doubt. Give a try, this is the only way you can acquire more knowledge. Keep in mind that xaml-C# era will end soon. Try learning native codes.

Comment: well I have fare amount of knowledge of GCC and TCC, but not of Direct X :(, but will sure give a try

Answer (score 1):

Actually MS has provided powerful image process API and support Shade language, below is a good sample.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Metro-Style-lightweight-24589f50